# is it possible to add in selenium and send keys?

Tags: python, selenium

I feel like there is a way to do this faster, I have been reading in the doc's and I cant find anything.

this is it:

```
driver.get('thewebsite');

loosers = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ' //*[@id=");


loosers.send_keys('11');

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ' //*[@id= ').click();``
sleep(30)

looser.send_keys('22');

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ' //*[@id= ').click();
sleep(30)  

loosers.send_keys('33');

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ' //*[@id= ').click();
sleep(30)  

looser.send_keys('44')
driver.find_element()(By.XPATH, ' //*[@id= ').click();
sleep(30)
```

So I want to send the number but plus 11 each time. My brain is fried I have been working on this for hours, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver.get('thewebsite');

input = 11

for i in xrange(1, 4):
    loosers = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ' //*[@id= ')
    loosers.send_keys(str(i*input))
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ' //*[@id= ').click()
    sleep(30)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, I should have been more specific I want to add 11 is that even possible? So like 100,111,122,133,144,155,etc.  I removes the i*input to i+input and it only goes up by one. And would it be possible to add to the end of that to so like 100987,111987,122987,133987,144987 155987. My original thought was to try and whip something up in crunch.

Comment: what is your use case for doing this? There might be a better way

Comment: @topjej If you want to add then you can do `input += 11` and `loosers.send_keys(str(input))` in the loop but I don't see how that's any better than multiplying. If you want it in the middle then `loosers.send_keys('1%d987' % input)`

Comment: Im testing to see if the numbers are correct its hard to explain and english isnt my first language so thanks for your patience.  So its looks like this 100 not a good number, 111 is a good number, 112 bad number, 122 good number.

Comment: so really 100987 not a good number, 111987 is a good number, 112987 bad number, 122087 good.

Comment: think you may need to define your own [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) for the numbers. Can't help you without knowing how you come up with these numbers